# UiSegmentedControler changing views

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to use this segmented control to display some information but I have found it difficult to do so. Here is my code:

```
@synthesize segmentedControl;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSArray *itemArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Player 1", @"Player 2", nil];
    segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:itemArray];
    segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(12, 100, 350, 30);
    [segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentAction) forControlEvents: UIControlEventValueChanged];
    segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
    [self.view addSubview:segmentedControl];

}

-(void) segmentAction {

    if (segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
        self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

    }
   if (segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {
   self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

   }
}
```

When I run this code, the view only changes colors after I have clicked the second segment. I want to be able to see green on the first view controller without being able to have to click the second view controller. I believe it has to do something with the UIControlEventChanged. How can I make this so it will work as I want it to?

Comment: can you try moving your code to viewdidappear?

Comment: @Mr.T It didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Your method `-(void) segmentAction` will get called when you click on any of the segments. So you need to set colour for `firstViewController` in `viewDidLoad`. Then you will be able to change the colour of views on segment taps.

Comment: This is just part of anothe program that I am using. The problem is that when a user enters information into a UItextfield, it wont be there when they come back to the first segment